# WAFileLibrary alternative

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

1)I had a set of ".js" files in a particular Directory structure. 
2)I NEED to store them locally with my smalltalk image and need not want to host them seperately.
3) I DONT need to keep them  inside the smalltalk image, with the WAFileLibrary.

Please let me know how  the following code needs to be modified for my requirement.

**anHtmlRoot javascript url: 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'.**

Something like the following..?

**anHtmlRoot javascript url: "/myfolder/MyFile.js"**

Help

Varun Isac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed write:

```
anHtmlRoot javascript url: '/myfolder/MyFile.js'
```

but it's better to use:

```
    anHtmlRoot javascript resourceUrl: 'MyFile.js'
```

Which allows you to setup the path as a configuration parameter. More on that in the [Seaside book](http://book.seaside.st/book/in-action/serving-files/images).

To serve the actual file, there are two options:

- serve the file from disk with an external webserver (on the same
  machine)
- serve the file from disk using the internal Smalltalk
  webserver

For the latter option, you can load the Seaside-Filesystem package from the [Seaside30LGPL repository](http://www.squeaksource.com/Seaside30LGPL/). Once loaded, you can define an 'external directory' handler for your 'myFolder' directory using the Seaside config tool and that handler will serve the files from the disk.